# Align outer cricle's navigation to inner circle's selected navigation

Tags: javascript, geometry, wheelnav.js

This is my code for demonstration purposes
https://jsbin.com/mugosec/65/edit?js,output

This is what I am trying to acheive:
If I click on the inner circle, I want the visible nav items of the outer circle to center to the inner circle's nav item. So far I can successfully and consistently have the outer circle navItems start at the start of the inner circle nav item. I use the inner circle navitem's baseAngle + the outer circle's visible navItems degrees to arrange my outer circle appropriately.

```
let wheelSliceAngle = 360 / this.wheel.navItemCount;
let text_labels = (mod_options.length) + 1;
let subWheelSliceAngle = 360 / (sub_wheel_labels.length);
let labels_length = sub_wheel_labels.length
let non_text_labels = non_text_labels_length
let x  = (subWheelSliceAngle * non_text_labels);
let y = (subWheelSliceAngle * text_labels);
for (let portion of this.wheel.navItems) {
    console.log('portion baseAngle',portion)
    let sub_wheel_var = y
    let wheel_var = portion.baseAngle
    let angle = wheel_var + sub_wheel_var
    portion.sub_wheel = initSubWheel(this.wheel, angle);
    portion.sub_wheel.hide()
    let wheel_nav = portion;
    let _that = this;
    let old_refresh = wheel_nav.refreshNavItem;
    //     console.log(portion);
    wheel_nav.refreshNavItem = function() {
        old_refresh.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    wheel_nav.navigateFunction = function() {
        resetMarkers()
        this.wheelnav.hideSubMenus();
        full_portion_sub_wheel.hide()
        this.sub_wheel.show();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.sub_wheel.navItems.map(x => x.selected = false);
            this.sub_wheel.navItems.forEach((v, i) => { v.setSelected() })
            this.refreshNavItem();
        }, 0)
    }
}
```

If I adjust the variables `sub_wheel_var` and `wheel_var` from:

```
let y = (subWheelSliceAngle * text_labels);
let sub_wheel_var = y
let wheel_var = portion.baseAngle
let angle = wheel_var + sub_wheel_var
```

to:

```
let y = (subWheelSliceAngle * text_labels);
let sub_wheel_var = y
let wheel_var = portion.navAngle
let angle = wheel_var + sub_wheel_var
```

I can have the OuterCircleNav start at the middle of the ICNI.

What I really would like to do is to have the OCN's middle match the ICNI's middle.

Doing this:

```
let y = (subWheelSliceAngle * text_labels);
let sub_wheel_var = y/2
let wheel_var = portion.navAngle
let angle = wheel_var + sub_wheel_var
```

Allows me to get close. The issue is that it's not quite accurate!!!! And no matter what I do, I can't get it to be dead center.

To mess around with the code easier, I've also added variables `sections` and `extras` to make it easier to add additional sections or additional outer nav elements respectively. Ive found that if I can get something working for one combination of sections and extras, a different combination will be skewed. I know that the answer lies in how I am calculating `y`, or `subWheelSliceAngle`, or `sub_wheel_var`.

Once more you may view the code here:
https://jsbin.com/mugosec/65/edit?js,output

I would absolutely appreciate any and all help.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `navItemsContinuous` property in `initSubWheel`.

```
  sub_wheel.navAngle = nav_angle-30;
  sub_wheel.sliceAngle = 30;
  sub_wheel.navItemsContinuous = true;
```

Here is my modified bin: https://jsbin.com/bicunuqexu/edit?js,output